# Reverse x axes positions on twin plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use `MatplotLib` and `Seaborn` to create a plot with two x axes and two y axes.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Event','Count'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = ax.twiny()

sns.kdeplot(data2, bw=0.5, ax=ax1, color='r')
sns.barplot(x='Event', y='Count', data=df, color="b")
```

What I want to do is to reverse the positions of the two X axes. So the bottom x Axis will be on top and the top will be on bottom.

Comment: Wouldn't that be quasi automatically the case if you plot the barplot to the `ax2`, `sns.barplot(, ..., ax = ax2)`?

Comment: If I add the `ax=ax2` on barplot and keep the `ax1` to kdeplot, nothing changes. If I remove it, it's a mess :P

Comment: Well, there may not be anything changing visually, but `sns.barplot(, ..., ax = ax2)` ensures the barplot sits in the axes which has its xaxis on top. Possibly you want to use `sns.barplot(, ..., ax = ax)`, to get it to the bottom. Of course feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue, such that people can reproduce it.